# How to add a field in Django User Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have three different types of users in my project. 
The three models have OneToOneField with the User model.

In many cases, I want to figure out which of the three type the user is. 
Is there a quick way to do that?

I'm thinking to add a field in User model but not sure how that can be done.

Comment: If you just want to distinguish between three kinds of users, you might be better off just using user groups (build in), and test for membership.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the `User` model with your extra fields, you can use `AbstractUser` model. This will provide you with all the `User` fields like `username`, `email` and etc. Then, add all the extra fields in `MyUser` model.

You need to do something like:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
   my_extra_field = .. # your extra field
```

This will provide all the `User` fields along with the extra field named `my_extra_field` in `MyUser` model.

Comment: Thanks. How do I relate the three types of users with the abstract model?

Comment: You can relate the 3 models with `MyUser` model using `OneToOneField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` interface, take an example of `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser` which extends `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a choice of what kind of user it is, I would try something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```